# Adjective of quality problem

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

Why is **He is cowardly** not correct as *cowardly* is acting as an adjective of quality?

While **He is intelligent** is correct.

Comment: *He is cowardly* is fine, although I think most people would say *he's a coward*.

Comment: I'd call the second incorrect on account of the spelling.

Comment: If "he is cowardly" is not correct then how could there be a Cowardly Lion?

Answer (score 1):

**Both "He is cowardly" and "He is intelligent" are correct.**

English does not distinguish between adjectives of quality and adjectives of condition. In both cases the verb "to be" is used in exactly the same way. This is different from (for example) Spanish, which has different verbs, *ser* and *estar*, depending on the adjective.